# Access VBA - print last record from SQL Query

Tags: ms-access, debugging, vba

I have the following SQL Query I'm executing and I'm trying to find why it returns the error 'overflow' when running the query.

Now I want to print the last record that it computes before going into overflow, is this possible using MS Access VBA?

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    sql = "SELECT DatumNaarWeeknummer([tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![RegistratieDatum]) AS WeeknummerGezaagdeOmzet, " _
    & "Sum([TotaalPrijs]/([tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal]*[Totaal])*[tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal]) AS GezaagdeOmzet " _
    & "FROM (((tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder LEFT JOIN qry_Actieve_Orders ON tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder.OrderID = qry_Actieve_Orders.OrderID) LEFT JOIN qry_ArtikelPerOrderID_EenheidsPrijsBijFranco ON tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder.ArtikelsPerOrderID = qry_ArtikelPerOrderID_EenheidsPrijsBijFranco.ArtikelsPerOrderID) " _
    & "LEFT JOIN qry_AantalArtikelTypesPerArtikelPerOrder ON tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder.ArtikelsPerOrderID = qry_AantalArtikelTypesPerArtikelPerOrder.ArtikelsPerOrderID) " _
    & "RIGHT JOIN tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst ON tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder.ArtikelsPerOrderID = tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst.ArtikelsPerOrderID " _
    & "GROUP BY DatumNaarWeeknummer([tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![RegistratieDatum]);"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Edit:** rearranged to focus on likely culprit)

No, you can't get the last record easily.  You can try `Select Top 5000 . . .` etc., raise the value if it works, and lower the value if it doesn't, and zero in on it that way.  But, it is unlikely that a particular is record is causing the problem.  I don't think there's *bad data* somewhere.  It's the query.

Focus on the Sum in the select query.  Take that out, and you'll likely have the query work.  It could well be that the sum overwhelms the numeric type that sql is using to add your values.  Actually, the more I think about it, this is probably it.  Yeah.  If it is, you'll need to force that to a type that can handle larger numbers, like this:

`SELECT blah blah, SUM(CAST([TotaalPrijs]/([tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal]*[Totaal])*[tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal] AS DECIMAL)) AS GezaagdeOmzet`

The syntax might be slightly different for MSAccess, but it will be something like that.  Being Access, the default might be int, in which case you might be able to specify Long.  Otherwise, specify Decimal.  Try to avoid the Real numbers if you can (single, etc.) and they can mess you up if you're not careful.

Though less likely, here are some other possible culprits:

- Are you sure this query is logically
  correct?  This query can be caused by
  too large a result set being
  returned.  Use the `Select Top 1000
  etc.` syntax, and analyze the results
  to make sure your joins are working
  as you wish, and aren't mistakenly
  causing [cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) results, for
  example.
- If your query is returning legitimate
  results, then might it be that the
  legitimate result are too massive? 
  If you really should be getting a
  billion results, and this is too
  much, then you'll have to change your
  whole strategy, or reduce the columns
  being returned, etc.

Comment: The query worked until a few days ago, then some new data was added and it stopped working...

Comment: Gotcha.  My guess (and Tomalak's I imagine) is that the new data cause the sum to be too big, rather than the data itself being bad.  Of course, if you new records mistakenly had massive values in them, that would also cause this.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this expression:

```
Sum([TotaalPrijs]/([tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal]*[Totaal])*[tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal])
```

produces an numeric overflow for some records. No knowing what data types your columns use, I can only recommend trying to convert them to a "bigger" data type during the calculation.

Comment: Any way I can loop through all records with this sql query to find out where this overflow might be?

Comment: Just convert the expression to the next bigger data type. You'll have to do it anyway, eventually. Of course you can select all numbers individually, and calculate the number in a VBA `While Not rs.EOF … Wend` loop, but that does not fix your query. ;-)

Comment: btw: what data type does one need for a number with loads of decimal place digits.  Most of these datatypes are Long Ints

Comment: so how do I convert the expression to the next biggest datatype?  Cause it does not specify a datatype anywhere? (in the expression that is)

Comment: The type of the result of a numeric expression is always the largest data type involved in it. So if one is `Long`, the whole thing is `Long`. Bigger would be `Double`, or choose yourself: http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/601315-vba-data-types. Use `CDbl()` etc. conversion functions to convert types.

Comment: Note that based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048744/ms-access-data-type-mismatch the problem was passing Nulls to a function that couldn't accept them.

Comment: @D W Fenton, not at this stage it wasn't, as can be seen from @Tony's query above, as far as I can tell, @Tony used the function in the link as a step in solving the problem with the original SQL as shown in the post above.

Comment: Well, sorry, but it was hard to follow the very confusing collection of questions that were all about the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the part of the query

```
([tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal]*[Totaal])*[tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal])
```

Is returning 0? If so that would cause an error, so it might not be large data that is at fault but data that is too small or non-existent

Comment: Yes it is possible that some of these are 0.  How would we solve that without having to do anything too extreme?

Comment: You could try wrapping it with an iif statement for example

IIf([My_value]=0,”put what you want to display if 0 is found”,”do you actual sum here”)