# MS Access - Data Type Mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the follow VBA code and it returns a '*data type mismatch in criteria expression*' while executing.  I cannot seem to find out why it is giving me this error.

Can anybody help me?

VBA:

```
Public Function GezaagdeOmzet(ByVal TotaalPrijs As Double, ByVal AantalArtiklesPerOrder As Double, ByVal TotaalArtiklesPerOrder As Double, ByVal AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst As Double) As Double

    Dim result As Double

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If IsNumeric(TotaalPrijs) = False Then
        MsgBox ("TotaalPrijs not a number")
        MsgBox (TotaalPrijs)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(AantalArtiklesPerOrder) = False Then
        MsgBox ("AantalArtiklesPerOrder not a number")
        MsgBox (AantalArtiklesPerOrder)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(TotaalArtiklesPerOrder) = False Then
        MsgBox ("TotaalArtiklesPerOrder not a number")
        MsgBox (TotaalArtiklesPerOrder)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst) = False Then
        MsgBox ("AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst not a number")
        MsgBox (AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst)
    End If

    If Not TotaalPrijs = 0 Then
        If AantalArtiklesPerOrder > 0 Then
            result = TotaalPrijs / (AantalArtiklesPerOrder * TotaalArtiklesPerOrder) * AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Else
            MsgBox ("AantalArtiklesPerOrder is null, Cannot do calculation")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("TotaalPrijs is null, cannot do division")
    End If

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("TotaalPrijs: " & TotaalPrijs & " TotaalArtiklesPerOrder: " & TotaalArtiklesPerOrder & " AantalArtiklesPerOrder: " & AantalArtiklesPerOrder & " AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst: " & AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst)
End Function
```

*SQL Query in MS Access*

```
GezaagdeOmzet: Sum(GezaagdeOmzet([TotaalPrijs],[tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal],[Totaal],[tbl_ArtikelVerwijderdUitZaaglijst]![Aantal]))
```

Is there anyway to catch the error I'm getting with VBA?

Cstr or CDec or CDbl is not handling this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above function is a little strange, as haarrrgh says.

It should look more like the code below. You do not need to check that each of the arguments (TotaalPrijs, ByVal AantalArtiklesPerOrder etc) is a number, because you pass them As Double. If you pass anything except a number, such as a letter or Null, you will get an error. If this is not what you want, consider passing the arguments As Variant, you can then check that they are numbers. However, as you are using this in a query, I suggest that you do not use message boxes, if the argument is null, make it zero, if that is what it is supposed to be.

Note also GezaagdeOmzet = , rather than result =

EDIT re Comments

```
Public Function GezaagdeOmzet(ByVal TotaalPrijs As Variant, _
    ByVal AantalArtiklesPerOrder As Variant, _
    ByVal TotaalArtiklesPerOrder As Variant, _
    ByVal AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst As Variant) As Double

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If (Nz(AantalArtiklesPerOrder,0) * Nz(TotaalArtiklesPerOrder,0)) * _
       Nz(AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst,0) = 0 Then
       GezaagdeOmzet = 0
    Else
        GezaagdeOmzet = Nz(TotaalPrijs,0) / _
        (Nz(AantalArtiklesPerOrder,0) * Nz(TotaalArtiklesPerOrder,0)) * _
       Nz(AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst,0)
    End If

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
   ' MsgBox ("TotaalPrijs: " & TotaalPrijs & " TotaalArtiklesPerOrder: " _
    & TotaalArtiklesPerOrder & " AantalArtiklesPerOrder: " & AantalArtiklesPerOrder _
    & " AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst: " _
    & AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Remou, but I'm stuck with the strange '#Error' in some of the fields returned by this function, when run inside a query?

Comment: You will get an error if you are passing nulls to your function, and I think you are.

Comment: so how do I get around these nulls? Is there a way to circumvent?

Comment: Yes I provide instructions above, use As Variant instead of As Double and either Nz or an If IsNull(...) Then to set nulls to zero.

Comment: I think if I were writing that function I'd explicitly coerce the output from all the Nz()'s to be CDbl's. I know VBA does implicit coercion, but I don't like depending on it always producing the results I expect. It's especially the case that I want to be explicit with this kind of thing when working with Variants.

Answer (score 2):

@Remou has provided what looks to me like a working solution, but he hasn't really fully explained why he implemented it differently. Here are some of the reasons:

1. the parameters for your original function are all defined as Double. These can be neither Null nor non-numeric, so all the tests for IsNumeric() in your original code are a waste of time since they will never return FALSE.
2. "data type mismatch in criteria expression" is a very common error message from queries that pass Nulls to user-defined functions that cannot accept Nulls in their parameters. Declaring your parameters as variants is one approach, but variants can lead to all sorts of issues and you lose strong data typing. I would recommend keeping the Double data types, and passing CDbl(Nz([TotaalPrijs],0)) from the original query.

Comment: @D W Fenton, you may wish to look at previous posts by @Tony where there has been a struggle with using CDbl & Nz in the query. I hope that the above function will help @Tony see his way clear to correcting the query, and that the function will become redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Why do run a function which returns a *double*, only to convert it to a string and sum it up (even it's only a single value)?
I don't get it.

What happens if you run the function directly, not in a query?
Does it throw an error as well?

And last but not least - there seem to be two bugs in the function, as it is now:

1) If TotaalArtiklesPerOrder or AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst are 0, it throws an error (which gets caught, but anyway...) because then you divide by zero in this line :

```
result = TotaalPrijs / (AantalArtiklesPerOrder * TotaalArtiklesPerOrder) * AantalArtiklesVerwijderedUitZaaglijst
```

You *do* check if TotaalPrijs is 0, but you're checking it the wrong way round: it's possible to divide zero by anything, but it's not possible to divide anything *by zero*.

2) The function will always return 0, because you calculate your result (in the variable "result"), but you don't return it.
You have to do this explicitly:

```
GezaagdeOmzet = result
```

Comment: I adjusted code to take care of possible divide by zero errors and also made sure that it actually return something.  I still get the error.  How would I run this by itself on the same tables?

Comment: Ok, Just ran this by itself, without the sum function it runs.  Now, in some of the rows it has '#Error', so could this be what causes the Sum function to give an error?

Comment: So, you mean you ran the same query, just without the sum() and your GezaagteOmzet() function and directly showing the columns like [tbl_ArtikelsPerOrder]![Aantal] instead, and THEN some of the fields showed "#Error"? If yes, I suppose the function works and there must be something wrong with your query.

Comment: It shows #error in the result field of the GezaagdeOmzet() function, so I'm not sure that it's not the function.  I'm running this in a Access Query. That's the only thing running in the query.  Some of the used fields are empty, could that be causing it?